# Check DataTable if a column exists and if it's null

Tags: c#, ado.net

Environment: .Net Framework 3.5

I have a `DataTable` that can bring back variable amount of columns for the same table in a database and I'm checking if the column `exists` and if it does is it `null` like the following:

This is when I'm mapping a `DataTable` to an `entity`

```
Status = dt.Columns["Status"] != null ? row["Status"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToInt16(row["Status"]) : 0,
```

Is this pretty standard or might I be missing any other case? Other more concise ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is better with <strike>Doodles</strike> extension methods:

```
public static class DataTableExtensions
{
    public static T GetValueOrDefault<T>(this DataRow row, string columnName)
    {
        return row.GetValueOrDefault<T>(columnName, default(T));
    }

    public static T GetValueOrDefault<T>(this DataRow row, string columnName, T defaultValue)
    {
        return row.Table.Columns[ColumnName] != null && 
               row[columnName] != DbNull.Value && 
               row[columnName] is T ? (T)row[columnName] : defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var Status = row.GetValueOrDefault<Int16>("status");
```

or

```
var Status = row.GetValueOrDefault<Int16>("status", -1);
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this with a DataReader directly to an entity instead of a datatable and then to the entity?

Comment: Yes. The code is sligjtly different, of course. In my profile there is a link to my github. There is only one repo tgere but it has a file called DataReader.Extensions.cs you can get the cose from there.

Comment: So my datetime field is coming back from the database as `DateTime.MinValue` when value is null. Is there a way to incorporate this in the extension method? The field in the entity class is defined as nullable `DateTime? DateCreate {get; set;}` It shows up in my gridvew as `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM` but I'd like it to be blank.

Comment: Are you sure it comes as min data from the database? It's more likely that somewhere on the way you are using a `DateTime` struct instead of a nullable of `DateTime`. I wouldn't recommend adding the code to this extension method but it's quite easy to write a method for "nullIf" in c#